# Getting error running couchdb 2.1 in docker

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

By Default couchDB should create 3 system databases but its not creating the system databases and giving error in docker

> {database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,403}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,378}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,407}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,91}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}

I am using it on linux 16.04LTS 64 bit .docker couchdb image x86_64-0.4.6 and couchdb version 2.1.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Facing same issue before some days it was working fine.but after I install couchdb outside the docker in physical system çouchdb in docker giving this error

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/#single-node-setup), you must create the `_users` database, and the other system databases:

```
curl -X PUT http://{url}/_users
curl -X PUT http://{url}/_replicator
curl -X PUT http://{url}/_global_changes
```

Comment: I do that but I am using couchdb with docker and hyperledger Fabric.Its not creating channel database also for channel in fabric

Comment: So add the appropriate command to create that database. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Flimzy is correct ... did you actually create the system databases as he mentions?   And are you sure that Fabric is not creating the statedb for you in any case?

Comment: I don't need to be familiar with those things to understand the error message you posted. If you have questions not related to that error message, post another question.